# How to start mysqld through mysqld_safe

Tags: server, mysql

**Specifications:**

MySQL Server version: 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Ubuntu-Server 14.04 LTS

Default MySQL-Config-File

**Question:**

Even after spending a long time I can not figure out why I can not start mysqld through mysqld_safe.

[MySQLDocs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqld-safe.html) are stating that:

> mysqld_safe is the recommended way to start a mysqld server on Unix and NetWare. mysqld_safe adds some safety features such as restarting the server when an error occurs and logging runtime information to an error log file.

Furthermore I understand that mysqld_safe is some kind of a wrapper around mysqld. When invoking mysqld_safe it will try to start mysqld.

**How to invoke mysqld_safe?**

There is no `init-script` in `/etc/init.d` named `mysqld_safe`. Only a script named `mysqld`.

Therefore

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

passes start directly to `/etc/init.d/mysqld`.
Where in `/etc/init.d/mysqld` it would jump to `case start` executing:

```
 # Start MySQL!
 /usr/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

**But** is mysqld_safe now running or not?

`ps -aux | grep my` gives following output:

```
mysql    31168  0.0  4.2 318348 43648 ?        Ssl  14:35   0:03 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

**and not**

```
mysql    31168  0.0  4.2 318348 43648 ?        Ssl  14:35   0:03 /usr/sbin/mysqld_safe
```

**Why?**

How can I start mysqld through mysqld_safe as I want to do the right way and not the lazy way like ''Ah, forget it.. at least it is working''.

I want to learn something..

Answer (score 1):

`mysqld_safe` is "angel" process which monitors MySQL and restarts it when it fails.

That way it was implemented originally. Some distributions now starts managing the processes itself and do not start `mysqld_safe`.

In Ubuntu 14.04 you may be able to to run `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` instead of `sudo service mysql start` for some mysql forks to be able to run mysqld_safe. (i.e. some options, for example jemalloc was using mysqld_safe).

Answer (score -1):

`mysqld_safe` is just a script to start up the `mysqld` daemon. It exits as soon as the daemon is up and running, that is why you don't see mysqld_safe running with `ps`. You would see it, though, if you were very fast.

Comment: Sure? Isn't mysqld_safe something like a monitoring program monitoring mysqld... which gives better recovery in case that mysqld exits abnormally? If so then it has to be an own process! Do I miss something?

Comment: No, there is no continuous monitoring in `mysqld_safe`.  As I said, it performs a large number of checks, starts up the server, and then exits. To see for yourself, you could modify the script to notify you at the exit points.